# Kendo datepicker limit the month values only from 0 to 12

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo datepicker of format MM/DD/YYYY and i have applied masking to it.

Now i want to limit the month values only from 1 to 12 even if the user tries to enter values manually such as 55 or 65 it should not allow the user to do so.

The same rule applies for date (i.e) date must allow values only from 0 to 31.

I am new to kendo please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restricting the user from typing in invalid values (which would be difficult - what would you do for copy pasted values when the user inexplicably sees values disappearing or not being pasted when your script corrects user input / or prevents data from being pasted, etc.), it would be easier to allow the user to **only select the date** (instead of typing it in) by either making the textbox readonly (you'd have to style the text box so that it is obvious to the user that it is readonly)

```
$("#datepicker").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

or by showing a label (or a readonly textbox styled like a label) in place of a textbox and have the user use the button alone to select the date.